# C# CA1006 No anidar tipos genéricos en firmas de miembro

Tags: c#

Saludos,

Ejecutando un análisis estático de código sobre una solución con C# me encuentro con el warning CA1006" No anidar tipos genéricos en firmas de miembro" en varias partes del código dónde se hace uso de un tipo genérico para pasarlo como argumento a un Func que esta dentro de un Expression:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetForMe(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, IEnumerable<T> entity);
```

La firma de arriba forma parte de una interface también generica dónde T es el tipo genérico.

El mensaje de la advertencia es claro para mi y viendo la documentación tiene mucho sentido que aparezca el warning y más si la categoria de este es "Diseño".

No obstante, no logro encontrar un modo "elegante" de "cambiar el diseño" de estas firmas. En la mayoría de partes dónde citan esta advertencia dicen que es mejor omitirl con el atributo `[SuppressMessage]`.

En la documentación de microsoft en: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182144.aspx dice:

> No suprima las advertencias de esta regla.Al proporcionar genéricos
>   con una sintaxis fácil de entender y utilizar se reduce el tiempo
>   necesario de aprendizaje y se aumenta la velocidad de adopción de
>   nuevas bibliotecas.

Idependiente de si la suprimo o no, realmente me gustaría saber cual sería la mejor manera de ajustar el diseño de la firma.

Gracias.

Comment: No creo que tenga nada que ver, pero no tendrias que añadir en la firma del método el tipo? `private IEnumerable<T> GetForMe<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, IEnumerable<T> entity)` De todas maneras, efectivamente parece que todo el mundo aconseja la supresión de ese warning.

Comment: @Pikoh si, ese fue mi primer intento, sin embargo, de esta manera también se están anidando los tipos genéricos para el delegado. Es decir, lo único que hice fue mover la advertencia a otro lugar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Al proporcionar genéricos con una sintaxis fácil de entender y utilizar se reduce el tiempo necesario de aprendizaje y se aumenta la velocidad de adopción de nuevas bibliotecas.

Esto suena muy bonito en la teoría. Pero en la práctica, ni siquiera Microsoft respeta siempre esta regla. De modo que, no te preocupes si tienes que suprimir la advertencia en ciertos lugares.

Por ejemplo, creo que la gran mayoría están de acuerdo que LINQ es sumamente poderoso y la vez expresivo, y que ha sido una tremenda mejora a la librería .NET. Sin embargo, cuando examinamos de cerca el API de LINQ, podemos ver que no respeta en absoluto la regla CA1006.

Un ejemplo concreto de esto, que se parece mucho al tuyo, lo encontramos en [IQueryable.Where()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx), cuya definición es:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
  this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
```

Obviamente, este ejemplo no respeta la regla CA1006. Pero, ¿acaso alguien dudaría de que esté diseñado correctamente? ¡Jamás!

Comment: Si @sstan pense lo mismo, solo que me negaba a creer que esto sucediera y queria evitar al máximo tener que suprimir las advertencias. Pero creo que por esta ocasión no hay otra alternativa. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que en tu caso específico sí está justificado anular la advertencia. `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` es un patrón de uso que está por todos lados por lo que no veo que sea un fallo de diseño de tu API.